# find endpoints for range given a value within the range

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am trying to solve a simple problem, but at the moment I cannot think of a better solution. I am testing an API that is not documented.

There is an ID used to fetch objects and it has a min and max value with random values missing in-between. I'm trying to test the responses I receive for random objects, but to find objects, I need to have valid IDs.

It would be very inefficient to test random numbers and hope that I get an object back. The best I can do is find a range, get a random number between that range and check if it exists before conducting tests.

A sample list of all of the IDs in the database might look like this:

```
[1005, 25984, 25986, 29587, 30000, ...]
```

Assuming the deviation from one value to another will never exceed `C`, e.g. from the first value to the next value, the difference will never be greater than a pre-defined constant, how would you calculate the min/max of the range given only one value in the range?

Starting from a given value and looping until the last value is found is horrible but that is how it was implemented by previous devs. Below is pseudocode that more or less covers what they do.

```
// this can be any valid object ID from the database
// assuming the ID's in the database are [1005, 25984, 25986, 29587, 30000]
// "i" could be any one of these values
var i = givenPredefinedObjectId;
var deviation = 100;

// objectWithIdExists() is going to lookup an object with the ID "i" in the database
// if there is no object with the ID "i" , it will return false
// otherwise the object will get tested and return true
while(objectWithIdExists(i)){
    i++;
}

for(i; i < i+deviation; i++){
    if(objectWithIdExists(i)){
        goto while loop;
    }
}

endPoint = i - deviation;
```

Assuming there is no knowledge about the possible values except you can check if they exist and you are given one valid value (there is no array with all possible IDs, that was just an example), how would you find the min/max values?

Comment: Can you add some examples in your question? For example, what would be a possible `givenPredefinedObjectId` and a possible outcome?

Comment: Ok, so for example if `i` is initialized to `25986` or any other ID that exists, you need to find `1005` and `30000`? So you're looking for the smallest and largest IDs?

Comment: Yes sir! But you don't know that those values exist until you manually call `objectWithIdExists(1005)`. You don't have any ID's from the database except the single one you are given. My goal is to find the endpoints and generate a random number between the min and max and check that in the database for testing later. To do that, I have to find the smallest and largest values in the least amount of calls to the database.

Comment: The ID's are essentially random numbers, but they are contained within a range. The best I can do is generate a random number between the min and max possible values and check if that is an object in the database or not.

Comment: Hum. I see. If you try to retrieve an object that does not exist with an ID greater than the largest ID stored in the database, is there a special error message, or there's no way to differentiate it? E.g. if you try to lookup 40000 does it tell you that it's out of range or it gives you the same error as if you tried to lookup 25985?

Comment: It's a terrible API. If the object does not exist, it will simply return nothing. It doesn't differentiate if it is smaller or larger than the range.

Comment: Then I don't see how you can do any better. If you could know that a request exceeded the largest ID, you could try to request IDs in increasing powers of 2 (e.g. request ID 1, ID 2, ID 4, ID 16, ...) until you pass the limit, then go back to the previous power of 2 and start again. Repeat until `curr_ID` is in range but `curr_ID+1` isn't. This would give you logarithmic time. But if there's no way to know that you're outside of the range, I don't think you have a choice but to live with that inefficient method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unbounded binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303402/guessing-an-unbounded-integer) is feasible, with a factor of `C` slowdown. Given an algorithm for unbounded binary search that, given access to the oracle `less_equal(n)` for some natural number `n`, returns `n` in time `O(log n)`, implement the oracle on input `k` by querying all of the IDs `C*k, C*k+1, ..., C*k+C-1` and reporting that `k` is less than or equal to `n` if and only if one ID is found. The running time is `O(C*log((max-min)/C))`.

Comment: I don't have access to the database itself, only the API that utilizes the database :(

Comment: @JosueEspinosa You don't need access with this method.